# Setting about users in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I am using the phpmyadmin in wamp server. I have create a new user, and I don't want this user can see all the database. I only want this user can see and modify some of the database that I allow to this user.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the best way to do this would be to create a new mysql user, and then login to phpmyadmin as that user.

How to create a new mysql user: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html

Once you have the user created, you can enable which databases that user can access as the mysql root user.

Comment: I have already create a new user, but I don't know hoe to set up to enable which databases that user can access.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is if you limit the user accounts access to specific databases in mysql using GRANT http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html, phpmyadmin will auto detect the logged in user and show him only those databases that he has privileges to use.

Comment: But I don't give the GRANT to this new user.

Comment: when you create the user, you should also be specifying what access levels the user has in the database right?

Answer (score 0):

From within phpMyAdmin, find the Users tab on the main page. Find your user and click the "Edit Privileges" link.

From there, it sounds like you want to un-check all of the Global privileges. Then scroll down to "Database-specific privileges" and select the database you want them to access from dropdown at "Add privileges on the following database:".

That will take you to another page where you can set the permissions for that specific database; it sounds like you probably want to check them all. Click the Go button and give it a try!